# In iOS Webview, javascript method is not getting called

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am calling certain javascript methods from the UIWebview which I have loaded on my view. 
There is one method which is created dynamically and added on the dom. 
I am not able to call that method using following piece of code.

```
NSString * isPinCorrect = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"showErrorStat()"];
```

Here is the function which appends it to dom

```
function appendToDom() {
        var error_js = document.createElement('script');
        error_js.type = 'text/javascript';
        error_js.innerHTML = "function showErrorStat() { Android.showErrorStat(); return 'false'; }";
        document.body.appendChild(error_js);
        //showErrorStat();
        //alert("error");
}
```

What possibly might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My webview reference was nil. That was the problem.